# Problema de "Cross-Origin Request Blocked" con JavaScript y método POST

Tags: javascript, http

Estoy intentando hacer un POST a una URL usando JavaScript pero el navegador me tira el siguiente error.

**Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://172.19.**.**:1236**/search. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).**

Le puse el Header que me pide pero sigue sin funcionar.

Dejo un poco de código:

```
function sendAJAX() {
const hpiNode = $('#hpiNode').val();
const indexName = $('#indexName').val();
const indexValue = $('#indexValue').val();
const div = $('#div');

var data = `{\n\t\"token\": \"1\",\n\t\"query\": [{\n\t\t\"index\": \"${hpiNode}",\n\t\t\"terms\": [{\n\t\t\t\"name\": \"${indexName}",\n\t\t\t\"value\": \"${indexValue}",\n\t\t\t\"operator\": \"like\"\n\t\t}],\n\t\t\"results\": {\n\t\t\t\"count\": 5000,\n\t\t\t\"sort\": [{\n\t\t\t\t\"name\": \"ISSUE_DATE\",\n\t\t\t\t\"order\": \"descending\"\n\t\t\t}],\n\t\t\t\"fields\": []\n\t\t}\n\t}]\n}`;

$('#form').on('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
});

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", () => {
    if (this.readyState === 4) {
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
        document.getElementById('div').innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
    }
});

xhr.open("POST", "http://172.**.**.**:12***/search");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
xhr.setRequestHeader("Postman-Token", "4dc1036e-c412-4aff-a970-2f89ac898a02");
xhr.send(data);
}
```

Quiero aclarar que la misma consulta usando POSTMAN me devuelve lo que necesito pero al hacerlo con mi código me tira el error que aclaro más arriba. Deduzco yo que el problema es del navegador, algo de tokens o similar, pero como no soy un experto me gustaría una respuesta más teórica de alguien que si sepa bien el porque del asunto.
Desde ya muchas gracias a todos !

Comment: lo mas probable es que sea un problema con la ruta, estas seguro que usas la ruta correcta?

Comment: Si, la ruta es correcta .. como explico más arriba la consulta con el Postman me anda correctamente pero al intentar hacerla con el navegador me tira el error que les consulto!

Comment: y esa ruta es de un servicio web tuyo? porque ese error por lo general no tiene nada que ver con el lado del cliente, debe ser habilitado en el lado del servidor

Comment: Claro, la ruta es de un servidor de la empresa. Para mi también deberían habilitarlo desde el servidor, esa es mi duda más que nada, pero necesito que alguien con experiencia me diga que estoy en lo cierto para poder elevarlo más arriba !

Comment: Igualmente quiero entender porque la consulta desde el Postman me da OK y desde el navegador no !

Comment: estás seguro que esa ruta te entrega un json?

Comment: Segurisimo, en el postman la respuesta es un JSON

Comment: es que es un poco difícil ayudarte si no envías el error completo con mensajes de error que probaste con console log y ese tipo de cosas, además de que pareces no tener acceso al servicio web, básicamente ayúdanos para poder ayudarte, con más información quizás sea posible ayudarte

Comment: Es que este es el único mensaje que me tira por consola: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://*******. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).  Este mensaje me lo da haciendo el console.log(xhr.responseText). Haciendo el console.error(xhr.responseText) me da el mismo error ... Hay algo más en lo que te pueda aportar para ayudarme ?? Soy Jr en esto, por eso pregunto. Y GRACIAS por enrroscarte con ayudarme :)

Comment: imprime en consola el objeto completo `console.log(xhr)`

Comment: Mismo problema ! Acá me dicen que estoy intentando de pegarle a un servidor con un lenguaje de Front - End y por eso no anda ... que debería programarlo con un lenguaje de back end así no tengo el problema de CORS

Answer (score -2):

El navegador bloquea esas peticiones cuando son desde un script, por eso te funciona desde *Postman*.

> "Por razones de seguridad, los navegadores restringen las solicitudes HTTP de origen cruzado iniciadas desde las secuencias de comandos. Por ejemplo, XMLHttpRequest y Fetch API siguen la misma política de origen. Esto significa que una aplicación web que utiliza esas API solo puede solicitar recursos HTTP del mismo origen desde el que se cargó la aplicación, a menos que la respuesta del otro origen incluya los encabezados CORS correctos."

Referencia:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

La cabecera **"Access-Control-Allow-Origin"** debe ser configurada en el servidor. Pueden añadir la IP desde la que haces la petición si no quieren poner `*`.

Comment: Gracias, pero ya conozco y tengo leida la documentación! necesito una explicación más concreta

Comment: Tengo el mismo problema. Pudiste resolverlo?